# Why do some hex numbers have a 2s compliment but some do not?

Tags: binary, hex

I want to write out the 2s compliment of the hex `0x1234`

As I understand the binary would look like: `0001 0010 0011 0100` and decimal `4660`

I was under the impression changing the leading 0 indicates positive vs negative, however online calculators aren't giving me any answer so my understanding of this is wrong

Alternatively looking at `0x8001` as an example: the decimal would be `32769` and the binary  `1000 0000 0000 0001`

Online calculators return an answer of  `-32767` as the 2s compliment

Could anyone please offer an explanation or some other post that explains in detail this concept of 2s compliment? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a number's two's complement by inverting all bits and then adding one to it. It must be agreed up front how many bits/digits are involved, i.e. what the word size is. For instance, the result will not be the same for 0x1234 and 0x00001234.

For your example (4 hex digits): 0x1234

In binary: 0b0001 0010 0011 0100

Invert bits: 0b1110 1101 1100 1011

Add one: 0b1110 1101 1100 1100

In hex: 0xEDCC

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, as a follow up why would 4660 not be represented as some negative number? For the other example the number 32769 is also represented as -32767. Just guessing I would assume something like -4659 or something along those lines?

Comment: Two's complement is the way that the minus is encoded in computer memory. The representation I gave is just listing the raw contents. The *interpretation* of that number will be negative, so at a higher level you would write that (probably in decimal notation) with a negative sign, but 2s complement is all about how a minus is encoded by 0/1 bits in memory -- there is no "minus" in bit-world, only 0 and 1. We can group 4 of those in a hex digit, which just is a shorter, convenient representation of bits.